# About Watchdog Timer

Tags: embedded

Can anyone tell me whether we should enable or disable watch dog during the startup/boot code executes?  My friend told me that we usually disable watch dog in the boot code. Can anyone one tell me what is the advantage or disadvantage of doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on your project.  The watchdog is there to help you ensure that your program won't get "stuck" while executing code. -- If there is a chance that your program may hang during the boot-procedure, it may make sense to incorporate the watchdog there too.

That being said, I generally start the watchdog at the end of my boot-up procedures.

Answer (score 3):

Usually the WD (watchdog) is enabled after the boot-up procedure, because this is when the program enters its "loop" and periodically kicks the WD. During boot-up, by which I suppose you mean linear initialization of hardware and peripherals, there's much less periodicity in your code and hard to insert a WD kicking cycle.

Answer (score 3):

Production code should always enable the watchdog.  Hobby and/or prototype projects are obviously a special case that may not require the watchdog.

If the watchdog is enabled during boot, there is a special case which must be considered.  Erasing and writing memory take a long time (erasing an entire device may take seconds to complete).  So you must insure that your erase and write routines periodically service the watchdog to prevent a reset.

Answer (score 3):

If you're debugging, you want it off or the device will reboot on your when you try to step through code. Otherwise it's up to you. I've seen watchdogs save projects' butts and I've seen watchdogs lead to inadvertent reboot loops that cause customers to clog up the support lines and thus cost the company a ton.

You make the call.

Answer (score 3):

The best practice would be to have the watchdog activate automatically on power up. If your hardware is not designed for that then switch it on as soon as possible. Generally I set the watchdog up for long duration during boot up but once I am past boot up I go for a short time out and service the watchdog regularly.

You might not always be around to reset a board that hanged after a plant shut down and restart at a remote location. Or the board is located in a inaccessible basement crawl space and it did not restart after a power dip. Lab easy practices is not real world best practices.

Try and design your hardware so that your software can check the reset cause at boot up and report. If you get a watchdog timeout you need to know because it is a failure in your system and ignoring it can cause problems later.

It is easier to debug with the watchdog off but during development regularly test with the watchdog on to ensure everything is on track.

Answer (score 2):

I always have it enabled. What is the advantage of disabling it? So what if I have to reset it during the bootup code?

Answer (score 2):

Watchdogs IMHO serve three two, but distinct, primary purposes, along with a third, less-strongly-related purpose: (1) Ensure that in all cases where the system is knocked out of whack, it will recover, eventually; (2) Ensure that when hardware is enabled which must not go too long without service, anything that would prevent such servicing shuts down the system, reasonably quickly; (3) Provide a means by which a system can go to sleep for awhile, without sleeping forever.

While disabling a watchdog during a boot loader may not interfere with purpose #2, it may interfere with purpose #1.  My preference is to leave watchdogs enabled during a boot loader, and have the boot loader hit the watchdog any time something happens to indicate that the system is really supposed to be in the boot loader (e.g. every time it receives a valid boot-loader-command packet).  On one project where I didn't do this, and just had the boot loader blindly feed the watchdog, static zaps  could sometimes knock units into bootloader mode where they would sit, forever.  Having watchdog kick the system out of the boot loader when no actual boot-loading is going on alleviates that problem.

Incidentally, if I were designing my 'ideal' embedded-watchdog circuit, I would have a hardware-configurable parameter for maximum watchdog time, and would have software settings for 'requested watchdog time' and 'maximum watchdog time'.  Initially, both software settings would be set to maximum; any time the watchdog is fed, the time would be set to the minimum of the three settings.  Software could change the 'requested watchdog time' any time, to any value; the 'maximum watchdog time' setting could be decreased at any time, but could only be increased via system reset.

BTW, I might also include a "periodic reset" timer, which would force the system to unconditionally reset at some interval.  Software would not be able to override the behavior of this timer, but would be able to query it and request a reset early.  Even systems which try to do everything right with a watchdog can still fall into states which are 'broken' but the watchdog gets fed just fine.  If periodic scheduled downtime is acceptable, periodic resets can avoid such issues.  One may minimize the effect of such resets on system usefulness by performing them early whenever it wouldn't disrupt some action in progress which would be disrupted.  For example, if the reset interval is set to seven hours one could, any time the clock got down to one hour, ask that no further actions be requested, wait a few seconds to see if anyone tried to send an action just as they were asked to stop, and if no actions were requested, reset, and then invite further requests.  A request which would have been sent just as the system was about to reset would be delayed until after the reset occurred, but provided no requests would take longer than an hour to complete, no requests would be lost or disrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Fewer transistors switching, I suppose, so minuscule power savings. Depending on how much you sleep, this might actually be a big savings. Your friend might be referring to the practice of turning off the WDT when you're actually doing something, then turning it on when you sleep.  There's a nice little point that Microchip gives about [their PICs](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39697a.pdf):

"If the WDT is disabled during normal operation (FWDTEN = 0), then the SWDTEN bit (RCON<5>) can be used to turn on the WDT just before entering Sleep mode"